# How do you escape colon (:) in Properties file?

Tags: java, properties, escaping, key-value

I am using a properties file to store my application's configuration values.
In one of the instances, I have to store a value as
`xxx:yyy:zzz`. When I do that, the colon is escaped with a back slash`\` resulting in the value showing as `xxx\:yyy\:zzz` in the properties file.

I am aware that the colon `:` is a standard delimiter of the `Properties` Java class. However I still need to save the value without the back slash `\`.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: I fear you can't. Otherwise, how could the property files be read back without confusing "your" colons, and colons use to delimit key values?

Comment: Make a StringWriter, write your properties file into it, go through the buffer line-by-line looking for `"\:"`, and replacing it by a single `":"`. This is not pretty, but then again what you are trying to do is also not very pretty.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani 'Use regular expressions' for that *how?* Where exactly do you get a chance to specify a regular expression when saving a properties file, and what exactly would the RE look like?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Put the properties into the `Properties` object and save it using a `store(...)` method.  The method will perform any escaping required.  The [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29) says:

> *"... For the key, all space characters are written with a preceding \ character. For the element, leading space characters, but not embedded or trailing space characters, are written with a preceding \ character. The key and element characters #, !, =, and : are written with a preceding backslash to ensure that they are properly loaded."*

You only need to manually escape characters if you are creating / writing the file by hand.

---

Conversely, if you want the file to contain unescaped colon characters, you are out of luck.  Such a file is malformed and probably won't load properly using the `Properties.load(...)` methods.  If you go down this route, you'll need to implement your own custom load and/or store methods.

Answer (score 8):

I came across the same issue. Forward slashes `/` also get escaped by the `store()` method in `Properties`.

I solved this issue by creating my own `CustomProperties` class (extending `java.util.Properties`) and commenting out the call to `saveConvert()` in the `customStore0()` method.

Here is my `CustomProperties` class:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;

public class CustomProperties extends Properties {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Override
  public void store(OutputStream out, String comments) throws IOException {
      customStore0(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "8859_1")),
                   comments, true);
  }
  //Override to stop '/' or ':' chars from being replaced by not called 
  //saveConvert(key, true, escUnicode)
  private void customStore0(BufferedWriter bw, String comments, boolean escUnicode)
          throws IOException {
      bw.write("#" + new Date().toString());
      bw.newLine();
      synchronized (this) {
          for (Enumeration e = keys(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
              String key = (String) e.nextElement();
              String val = (String) get(key);
              // Commented out to stop '/' or ':' chars being replaced
              //key = saveConvert(key, true, escUnicode);
              //val = saveConvert(val, false, escUnicode);
              bw.write(key + "=" + val);
              bw.newLine();
          }
      }
      bw.flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, my problem here is that when saving a property, Java is interpreting the property value and if it finds for example this: '\n' it does a line break and saves a new property so the result is 2 property instead of one, any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

We hit this question a couple of days ago. We were manipulating existing properties files with URLs as values.

It's risky but if your property values are less than 40 characters then you can use the "list" method instead of "store":

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#list(java.io.PrintWriter)

We had a quick look at the JDK code and hacked out a custom implementation of store that works for our purposes:

```
public void store(Properties props, String propertyFilePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(propertyFilePath); 
    for (Enumeration e = props.propertyNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
        String key = (String) e.nextElement();
        pw.println(key + "=" + props.getProperty(key));
    }
    pw.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the xml variant of the properties file (using `loadFromXML` and `storeToXML`) this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I like this approach too, but XML format is bit harder to read for noobs ("customers etc.")... I think there should be way how to escape :, or either use some utils to choose key value delimiter, as now : is taken as delimiter too...

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked by using `\` before special character,

e.g,

```
Before: VCS\u003aIC\u0020Server\u003a=Migration
After: VCS\:IC\ Server\:=Migration
```

`:` is escaped with `\:` and   (space) with `\`  (`\` followed by <Space>).

For more info : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

Answer (score 1):

For people like me that get here for this when using Spring Boot configuration properties files: You need to enclose in `[..]`:

E.g.:

```
my.test\:key=value
```

is not enough, you need this in your `application.properties` for example:

```
my.[test\:key]=value
```

See also [SpringBoot2 ConfigurationProperties removes colon from yaml keys](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11386)

Answer (score 0):

Its simple,
just use **Apostrophe** **'   '** over there
E.g.:

Instead of this(case 1)

```
File file= new File("f:\\properties\\gog\\esave\\apple");
prop.setProperty("basedir",file.toString());
```

**Use this(case 2)**

```
File file= new File("f':'\\properties\\gog\\esave\\apple");
prop.setProperty("basedir",file.toString());
```

Output will be

---

Case 1: `basedir = f\:\\properties\\gog\\esave\\apple`

Case 2: `basedir = f:\\properties\\gog\\esave\\apple`

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

**Try using unicode.**

The unicode for a colon is`\u003A`

Additionally the unicode for a space is: `\u0020`

For a list of basic Latin characters see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)

**For example:**

`ProperName\u003A\NameContinues=Some property value`

Will expect a property with a key:

`ProperName:NameContinues`

And will have a value of:

`Some property value`