# How to write url with ant

Tags: java, ant

I want to update an url that is a string comming from a izpack configuration.
When I run the ant script I have an issue writing the config file.

For example:
the correct way to write the url in my property file is url=http://xxx.x.x.x:8080/consola

But ant the end of the write process I obtain url=http\://xxx.x.x.x\:8080/consola

As you can see the "\" character is not a part of the url.

Here is the part of the script that is writing my config file:

```
<target name="writeConfig">
    <echo message="${isAppUpdate}" />
    <var name="updateFlagCremona" value="${isAppUpdate}" />

    <propertyfile file="../config/config.properties" />

    <property name="main.url" value="${mainUrl}" />
    <property name="bckup.url" value="${bckupUrl}" />

    <propertyfile file="../config/config.properties">
        <entry key="url" operation="=" value="@mainUrl" />
        <entry key="urlBackup" operation="=" value="@bckupUrl" />
    </propertyfile>

    <replace file="../config/config.properties" token="@mainUrl" value="${main.url}" />
    <replace file="../config/config.properties" token="@bckupUrl" value="${bckup.url}" />

    <if>
        <equals arg1="${updateFlagCremona}" arg2="yes" />

        <then>

            <echo message="${mainUrl}" />
            <echo message="${bckupUrl}" />
            <echo message="${consoleId}" />

            <propertyfile file="../config/config.properties">
                <entry key="url" value="${mainUrl}" />
                <entry key="urlBackup" value="${bckupUrl}" />
                <entry key="console.id" value="${consoleId}" />
            </propertyfile>
        </then>
    </if>
</target>
```

What I doing wrong?

Comment: This is no error. Colons are escaped in property files. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699055/how-to-escape-colon-in-properties-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work around would be just remove the extra \ from the variable here is an working example for you :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <project name="Hello World Project" default="info">
    <property name="url" value="http\://xxx.x.x.x\:8080/consola"/>
   <target name="info">
      <echo>before : ${url}</echo>


    <property name="before" value="This is a value"/>
    <script language="javascript">
        var before = project.getProperty("url");
        project.setProperty("after", before.replace("\\", ""));
    </script>
    <echo>after=${after}</echo>

   </target>
</project>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the mistake !

I was escaping the colons but in the wrong order.

I just change my script in that way:

```
<target name="writeConfig">
    <echo message="${isAppUpdate}" />
    <var name="updateFlag" value="${isAppUpdate}" />

    <if>
        <equals arg1="${updateFlag}" arg2="yes" />

        <then>
            <echo message="${mainUrl}" />
            <echo message="${bckupUrl}" />

            <propertyfile file="../config/config.properties" >
                <entry key="url" value="${mainUrl}" />
                <entry key="urlBackup" value="${bckupUrl}" />

            </propertyfile>
        </then>
    </if>

    <property name="main.url" value="${mainUrl}" />
    <property name="bckup.url" value="${bckupUrl}" />

    <propertyfile file="../config/config.properties">
        <entry key="url" operation="=" value="@mainUrl" />
        <entry key="urlBackup" operation="=" value="@bckupUrl" />
    </propertyfile>

    <replace file="../config/config.properties" token="@mainUrl" value="${main.url}" />
    <replace file="../config/config.properties" token="@bckupUrl" value="${bckup.url}" />


</target>
```