# Spring confuse string after : with port in JDBC datasource URL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

Here's my spring datasource url defined in **application.properties** :

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://uqg0qy4dfypoknm9:3d0Ybm2rHkeHzj@bh0pq6ext2z8j-mysql.ssssss.ssssss.com:3306/bhwxhozmc0pq6ext2z8j?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Thing is, spring confuse the string after the two points : with the port and gives me this exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5XVEsGBHt7Uc0cGs4S5w@bwxbfvcnpboerdqh937j
```

How can i tell spring the : is part of the url not port.

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Use \ character in front of the first : character.
In your case it is

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://uqg0qy4dfypoknm9\:3d0Ybm2rHkeHzj@bh0pq6ext2z8j-mysql.ssssss.ssssss.com:3306/bhwxhozmc0pq6ext2z8j?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Comment: Try using \\ and let me know

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699055/how-do-you-escape-colon-in-properties-file

Comment: Try / and // once for me please.

Comment: it gives me ** java.net.UnknownHostException: uqg0qy4dfypoknm9**

Comment: spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://"uqg0qy4dfypoknm9:3d0Ybm2rHkeHzj@bh0pq6ext2z8j-mysql.ssssss.ssssss.com":3306/bhwxhozmc0pq6ext2z8j?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC

Comment: The above mentioned for me when trying to connect mongo. Let us see if it works for you.

Comment: nope it didn't work either. im starting to think it's somethind in my pom or some dependancy..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it to use yaml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://uqg0qy4dfypoknm9:3d0Ybm2rHkeHzj@bh0pq6ext2z8j-mysql.ssssss.ssssss.com:3306/bhwxhozmc0pq6ext2z8j?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

or java configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .url("jdbc:mysql://uqg0qy4dfypoknm9:3d0Ybm2rHkeHzj@bh0pq6ext2z8j-mysql.ssssss.ssssss.com:3306/bhwxhozmc0pq6ext2z8j?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC")
                .build();
    }
```

to be honest using single string for database connection is a little rough

Comment: I tried yaml and java configuration like you said but i still have the same problem