# properties.store using FileOutputStream is adding an escaping character

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, fileoutputstream

I have this function to save in a file my properties:

```
 void saveProperties(Properties properties) {
    File file = new File("C:\\Files\\new.properties");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    properties.store(fileOutputStream, "Properties");
}
```

My problem is that when I want to save in a file the properties below using my function:

```
myPropertieTest1=Hi : friend
myPropertieTest2=#Bye
myPropertieTest3=!#:
```

My code added an escape character like this:

```
myPropertieTest=Hi \: friend
myPropertieTest2=\#Bye
myPropertieTest3=\!\#\:
```

How can I fix this? I need to save the properties as the originals (without the escape characters)

Comment: I've found similar question. May this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699055/how-do-you-escape-colon-in-properties-file

Comment: This is just how Java properties are stored, with the escapes.  If you don't want the escapes, then using Java properties isn't the way you should be doing it.

Comment: Hi @Atryom, my problem here is that after adapt my code like you show me in that post, now when saving a property, Java is interpreting the property and if it finds \n it does a line break and saves a new property , do you know the way to fix that?

Comment: I didn't quite catch. Are you trying to save a property, which name or value contains `\n` ?
If you have updated your code, could you please update the question as well